# IPython/Jupyter notebook widget span full width

Tags: widget, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

During IPython 3 times, I could make my custom `IPython.html.widgets.DOMWidget` span the full width of the notebook by setting it's `width` trait (corresponding to the CSS width of the widget `div`) to `100 %`. In Jupyter 4, that does not work anymore, the widget gets squashed to the left edge of the notebook. Web inspector tells me that the parent `div.widget-subarea` essentially has zero width up to padding. Is that a new feature or a bug? What is the exact widget API to achieve a full-width widget? I guess I'm bound for trouble if my widget's JS just sets the `width` of the parent wrapper to `100 %` as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, that was due to a bug in the version of Jupyter I was using. The style for `.widget-subarea` in `widget.css` has gained a `flex: 2 1 0%;` property since, which was missing before, despite `display: flex;`.